# different 401 errors depending on where authorization happens

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have a question regarding authorization in MVC3.
I'm currently looking at dening certain user access to the application.

I can du this in 2 ways. in the web.config (for global settings) or on the individual controllers (or actions).

But I see a different behaivour in these 2 approches.

when a user is denied access using web.config settings, they get a 401.2 error page stating "Access is denied.".

If they are denied access using a controller setting they still get a 401 response, but a blank page.